How to change doughnut hole size in VBA Excel
I want to change the size of my doughnut chart to 75% using the following:
chartObj.Chart.DoughnutHoleSize = 75

but I get a compile error: Method or data member not found
The doughnut hole size should change to 75%.

Apply something similar like this:
activesheet.chartobjects(1).chart.chartgroups(1).doughnutholesize=75
The result

